# python: multiprocessing.dummy using imap_unordered to iterate thru a growing/modifying list

Tags: python, list, loops, python-multithreading, pool

**Abstract**

- i would like to use multiple threads to process a list.
- while the list is processed, under some conditions, the list may be added to, so that the new additions should be processed as well. (it will not be infinite)
- the *output* from this processing may be large, and will only be iterated thru once. i don't see a reason to keep the entire thing in memory.
- the *output* can/should be processed immediately. ordering does not matter.

**Code**
to test the idea i wrote the following, using python 2.7.10 in windows:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as thPool
from time import sleep

def funct(n):
    #print "{"+str(n)+"}",
    #print "|"+str(len(li))+"|",
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n
    elif n % 3 == 0:
        li.append(12)
    elif n % 5 == 0:
        li.append(14)
    #sleep(.25)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    P = thPool(4)
    li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    lf=(i for i in P.imap_unordered(funct,li) if i is not None)
    #print lf
    for m in lf:
        print "("+str(m)+")",
        #sleep(.25)
```

what i expected was to get, in no particular order, the even numbers (2,4,6,8), two 12s, and one 14.

**Outcome**
i ran the above multiple times. i got different results each time:

- (2) (4) (6) (8) (12) (14) (12)
- (2) (4) (6) (8) (12) (14)
- (2) (4) (6) (8)

i assumed that the iterator finishes before the list is appended. i put a debug print statement inside *funct* to show the size of the global list *li* and i got:

- |9||9|  |9||9| |10||10| |10|  (2)|11||11| (4) (6) (8)
- |9||9| |9| |9||9| |11|(2)|11| |11||11| |11| |12| (4) (6) (8) (12) (14)
- |9||9| |9||9| |9| |10|  (2)|11|  (4)|11|  (6)|11| |12|(8) |12| |12|(12) (14) (12)

i also played around with creating delays, in case of a race condition, but that didn't seem to make a difference in predictability.

**Questions**

1. why is the outcome unpredictable? how come the list additions are *sometimes* not processed? (even though the size of the list inside the function is >9, meaning the list has been appended)
2. why is the *output* always ordered?
3. is there a proper way to do this using the multiprocessing.dummy pool functionality?
4. is there a suggested alternative method of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered` in this case. There are ways to make it work, but they're ugly and fragile. Use a producer-consumer pattern, where the consumers occasionally act as producers.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Process, Queue


def process(inq, outq):
    while True:
        n = inq.get()
        try:
            if n % 2 == 0:
                outq.put(n)  # Queue up for printing
            elif n % 3 == 0:
                inq.put(12)  # Queue up for future processing
            elif n % 5 == 0:
                inq.put(14)  # Queue up for future processing
        finally:
            inq.task_done()

def printer(q):
    while True:
        m = q.get()
        try:
            print "("+str(m)+")",
        finally:
            q.task_done()

def main():
    workqueue = Queue()
    printqueue = Queue()
    printworker = Process(target=printer, args=(printqueue,))
    printworker.daemon = True
    printworker.start()

    for i in range(4):
        processor = Process(target=process, args=(workqueue, printqueue))
        processor.daemon = True
        processor.start()

    li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    for x in li:
        workqueue.put(x)  # optionally, put all items before starting processor threads so initial work is processed strictly before generated work
    workqueue.join()  # Wait for all work, including new work, to be processed
    printqueue.join()  # Then wait for all the results to be printed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You could use `Queue` to build a generator to feed to `imap_unordered` that would roughly approximate what you want, but it would be extremely tricky, and involve some awful hacks (generators that intentionally block until they're sure the queue won't be extended); if the goal is to produce and consume work live, then do so, `imap_unordered` is fundamentally about transforming from independent inputs to independent outputs where the `map` function is (usually) idempotent and side-effect free; using it for other purposes is fighting its design goal.

Comment: interesting. a few questions about your code: 1) why run the processes as daemon's when you're joining them? 2) how are the processes exiting the 'while True' loop? 3) since work & print queue are global variables, is it necessary to pass them as an argument to the function?

Comment: i think get it. regarding my Q1,2: join()s block until task_done() is called the same number of times as put(). and then the main program exits which terminates the child processes (IOW exit the 'while True' loop), because they are daemons.

Comment: @displayNada: You got it. It was simpler to make the worker threads (they're really threads, since we're using `multiprocessing.dummy`) infinite loops, because the alternative is a shared `Event` with each `Queue.get` running in non-blocking or timed blocking mode (so it rechecks the `Event` every once in a while), which is more complicated than I wanted for a simple example. Beyond that, in Python 2, blocking `Queue.get` with a timeout is extremely inefficient, because timed waits aren't supported natively, so it's implemented as a poll and sleep loop, that creates massive GIL contention.

Comment: @displayNada: As for passing them to the functions, I find it useful to alias the queues to something meaningful in the function context (`process` just cares about `inq` vs. `outq`, not where the data comes from or goes to). In addition, it's good practice to try and write thread work functions to avoid mutating globals just so people don't need to check if there are dangerous side-effects. Sure, the whole point of Queues is that they're safe for multithread/multiprocess access, but it's still useful for maintainers to not need to search for possible shared data issues.

Comment: @displayNada: Oh, and the other reason for passing the queues as arguments: As written, this code could be used as an imported module (that provides the two defined worker functions) or executed as a standalone executable (i.e. as `__main__`). In the `__main__` case, we could just use the globals, but in the import case, writing modular code, we'd want to accept queues as arguments, so code using our module can pass in their own queues, rather than using global state (which doesn't even exist as written; `import`-ed, `workqueue` and `printqueue` aren't defined in the module at all).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I re-read the problem more clearly and understand that you want to modify the list on the fly.  This need to be done with a proper shared object (such as Array, Queue or even a Manager from the multiprocessing library) that is threadsafe.

Also, I unfortunately don't think you can use `imap_unordered()` in that case. I think the behavior you are seeing is due to the fact that `imap_unordered` is sometimes getting to the end of the iterable and stops handing out work **before** the additional items are being placed on the list.

Comment: Of course, this means that processing doesn't actually match what was expected. For the toy example, it doesn't output in the expected order (deferring large values for later), and it may not work at all when the new work is only loosely related to the work that created it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger What "toy example"?

Comment: The example code given in the question is described as "testing the idea", which I assume means there is a more complicated use case envisioned once the kinks are ironed out.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ah "toy" as in "just playing around", got it. Also, I re-read the ask and you are right. I updated my answer. I think the results he is seeing is because sometimes the iterator is finishing **before** the large items get added.